# ngTemplateOutlet not working in mat-table

Tags: angular, ng-template, mat-table

I'm trying to reuse some html components in angular as per the solution mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51086407/how-to-reuse-template-html-block-in-angular). In my scenario, I have 2 mat tables in a page, with some common columns. I'm trying to put the common columns in a template and reference that template inside my mat-table definitions. But it's not compiling, angular is not able to find the column definitions inside the template. [Here is the stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gyjevg) link. Please advise what am I missing.

Answer (score 0):

try using ViewChild:

```
@ViewChild('CommonColumns') CommonColumns: TemplateRef<any>;
```

Put that in your ts file. you're trying to reference something that doesn't exist in your ts file with [ngTemplateOutlet].

Comment: Thanks ! Updated the stackblitz with this code, but still getting the same error.

Comment: try looking at this it seems like what your looking for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52812422/angular-material-2-table-define-column-using-templateref-and-ngtemplateoutlet